# Problemas con la siguiente consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en MySql con los siguientes datos, donde `id_pers` es una foreign key a otra tabla personas.

```
--------------------------------------------
  id   |  id_pers  |    created_at         |
--------------------------------------------
   1   |      1    | 2016-09-12 16:59:11   |
--------------------------------------------
   2   |      1    | 2016-09-12 17:03:45   |
--------------------------------------------
  3    |      1    | 2016-09-12 17:03:30   |
--------------------------------------------
  4    |      2    | 2016-09-12 18:05:29   |
--------------------------------------------
  5    |      2    | 2016-09-12 18:03:00   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Como puedo sacar el ultimo registro insertado agrupado por `id_pers`.
La select que yo estoy realizando es:

```
select id, id_pers, max(created_at) as fecha_creacion
from observaciones group by id_pers
```

Lo que me devuelve:

```
--------------------------------------------
  id   |  id_pers  |    created_at         |
--------------------------------------------
  1    |      1    | 2016-09-12 17:03:45   |
--------------------------------------------
  4    |      2    | 2016-09-12 18:05:29   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Me devuelve un `id=1` en el primer registro cuando debería ser `id=2`. Sin embargo el `id=4` me lo devuelve bien.

Las columnas son de tipo `id => INT`, `id_pers => INT` y `created_at => TIMESTAMP`.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es obtener la máxima fecha por `id_pers` y luego puedes hacer un `JOIN` con la tabla original:

```
SELECT om.*
FROM observaciones o
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_pers, MAX(created_at) max_created
            FROM observaciones
            GROUP BY id_pers) om
    ON o.id_pers = om.id_pers
    AND o.created_at = om.max_created;
```

Answer (score 3):

Por qué el código de la pregunta no funciona:

- *Detection of Functional Dependence* [►](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Sé que sé poco sobre **MySQL**, pero me gustaría colaborar con otra alternativa, usando subconsultas sin `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM observaciones t
WHERE t.id =
(
    SELECT id
    FROM observaciones t1
    WHERE t1.id_pers = t.id_pers
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Código funcionando: [►](http://rextester.com/PFJHG24199)

Ese código lo pude hacer gracias a la siguiente documentación:

- *CREATE TABLE Syntax* [►](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)
- *Comment Syntax* [►](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html)
- *Subquery Syntax* [►](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)
- *Comparisons Using Subqueries* [♥](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparisons-using-subqueries.html)

No entendía por qué **MySQL** permite incluir en el `SELECT` campos que no están en el `GROUP BY`, pero las dudas se despejaron al leer:

- *GROUP BY Modifiers* [►](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
- *MySQL Handling of GROUP BY* [►](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)